# Web Service Exception: No XML Document

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Im creating a web service (my server is ubuntu vm, not using WAMP or XAMPP) but having an issue = Exception:looks like we got no XML document. I have searched the internet but there are mostly soap exceptions for this, but I am not having a soap fault. It is a plain exception. It is echoing hi, but not echoing hi4, so I guess the problem might be in the function viewHealthDetails (which is in my wsdl) but I am almost sure that my wsdl is correct as I have used it previously in another project. Please help.

```
if(isset($_POST['txtInput']))
{
    try
    {

    $input=$_POST['txtInput'];

    $wsdl='.../Search.wsdl';
    $options=array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client=new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
echo "hi";

    $response=$client->viewHealthDetails($input);

    echo "hi4";
    if(isset($response->HealthDetails))
    {

        $HTMLDocument="<!Doctype html>
        // My html code

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>This Health type is not in our categories!</h1>";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{

    echo 'Exception:'.$e->getmessage();


}
catch (SOAPFAULT $exception)
{
    echo 'SOAP Exception: '.$exception->getMessage();
}
}

    else
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is being thrown because the PHP cannot process the response XML correctly.  To troubleshoot the response, set your options array to:

`$options=array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, 'trace' => 1);`

then use `var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());` after making the request.  This will allow you to inspect the returned XML and validate it for correctness.  You may find there is other output that is breaking the XML.

Comment: getting a NULL and still the exception

Comment: Then you've discovered the reason for the exception - you're not getting an XML response from the web service, instead you get an empty NULL response.  You could also try using a tool like SoapUI to duplicate the call and confirm that the web service returns nothing.